# data table version of dplyr group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a `dplyr` version of group_by in which I try to cut a column called ratio into different ranges. It is working fine. I am not able to update `dplyr` to new version due to managed R studio (managed by a common admin). Is there any way to rewrite the same logic into `data.table` way

```
 output <- output %>%
      group_by(start = as.IDate(timestamp),VAV =  van_d, conditions = cut(output$ratio, breaks=c(0,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,100),labels=c("0-0.7","0.7-0.8","0.8-0.9","0.9-1",">1"))) %>%
      summarise(duration = n()) %>% 
      ungroup %>% 
        na.omit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `data.table`, the general usage is

```
 dt[i, j, by]
```

where `i` is the index to subset the rows i.e. it can take numeric or a logical expression, `j` - for the columns, and `by` for grouping.  This usage is applicable only to `data.table` objects.  So, if the input dataset is `data.frame` or `tibble`, convert to `data.table` with either `as.data.table` (wouldn't change the original object) or with `setDT` (which converts to `data.table` by reference).

Now, we specify the `i`, `j` and `by`.  In the `dplyr` code, there is no `filter`ing i.e. we don't need to specify the `i` - so it remains blank.  The `group_by` code will go into the `by`.  It can be a `list` or a syntax `.(`, then the `j` for `summarise` also is a `list` (`.(duration = .N)`).  The `.N` is similar to `n()` from `dplyr`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(output)[, .(duration = .N), 
  by = .(start = as.IDate(timestamp),VAV =  van_d, 
    conditions = cut(ratio, breaks=c(0,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,100),
             labels=c("0-0.7","0.7-0.8","0.8-0.9","0.9-1",">1"))]
```